# mod_rewrite short URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am using two Domains which one of them is the Main Domain (`http://www.domain.com`) and the second is a Domain to shorten URL's (`http://doma.in`)

Forwards should be like this

`http://domain.com` -> `http://www.domain.com`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

http:// doma.in -> http:// www. domain.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^doma.in [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`http://sub.domain.com` -> `http://sub.domain.com` (no configuration needed?!)

and now the important one

`http://doma.in/VC7s98X` -> should forward to its target without to be converted to `http:// www.domain.com`

I dont know how I can do this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second set of rules matches everything (`(.*)`) on the domain doma.in. To only match the bare domain without any trailing path, change the rule as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^doma.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That takes care of `http://doma.in/VC7s98X` not redirecting to `http://www.domain.com`. I'm assuming you have something in place to take care of `http://doma.in/VC7s98X` forwarding to its intended target ... if you're asking for help with that part, that's a much bigger question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. ^/?$ This helped me out. You are great!
One Problem is still there.. I can not call anymore the Subfolders :)

Comment: Ok Subfolder was my failure.. Nothing to do with this Script ;)